# Подскажите, где ошибка в моем регулярном выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Выводит no, если $surname = Пукин

Какого?

```
if (preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', $surname)){
 echo 'yes';
}else{
 echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в модификаторе Unicode.

Тогда регулярка будет такая:

```
  /^[А-Яа-я]+$/u
```

---

Вот пример:

```
 var_dump(preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', 'Пукин')); // -> int(0)
 var_dump(preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/u', 'Пукин')); // -> int(1)
```

Comment: интересно а Ёё ъЪ туда попадают ?

Comment: Не работает. Когда пишешь

    preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', 'Пукин'), все ок

если 

    preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', $surname), уже не работает

Comment: Ъъ - входит, Ё, к сожалению, нет. Если вам нужна и `Ё`. тогда:

       /^[А-Яа-яЁё]+$/u

Но ни как не то, что написали вы

Comment: /u - где ?

Comment: Я короч пересоздал файл, теперь все ок. Кроме одной проверки.

    $patronymic_teacher = История Украины
    preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', $patronymic_teacher))

Comment: @jkeks - абмансчик, где мой +? xD

Comment: ну все правильно, пробел-то включить надо тоже

Comment: @Zow я "**u**" в конце регулярки от нефиг делать думаешь написал?

Comment: у меня с /u все работает если файл в UTF кодировке.
Спасибо Zow

Comment: @jkeks в данном случае валидация одного слова, зачем пробел?
****
Пожалуйста :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope проблема была, в том, что я js файл валидации, создал в другом редакторе, и он оказался в другой кадировке

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так:

```
if (preg_match('/^[ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджжэячсмитьбю]+$/', $surname)){
 echo 'yes';
}else{
 echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: ты, не много книг не дочитал. 

Такая же регулярка на js работает

Comment: ну вариант не лучший, но рабочий

Comment: у JS может меньше пролемм, но раз люди специальные тулзы пишут для нормальной работы UTF, значит есть повод, вот почитай что это: http://code.google.com/p/php5-utf8/

Начало тут: http://forum.dklab.ru/php/advises/Php-funktsiiDlyaObrabotkiTekstaVKodirovkeUtf-8.html

Кстати если тут будет более красивое решение, сам заплюсую

Comment: вот тебе более красивое решение... ОМГ. @jkeks ты такое в реальных кодах писал? О__о

Comment: У меня вдоль и поперек все так исписано ;)
Шучу, я один раз сталкивался с этой бедой и задавал вопрос тут, мне как раз и указали на классы какие-то, ну а ссылки на Котеровых, там вообще аншлаг.
;)
Да в первый раз и делал как написал сам =)? ну теперь-то все мы Гуру ?